# A Multi-Level Up Css Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to find a way to use css selectors to format a specific parent div.  For example, in the following sample code...

```
<div id="one">
   <div id="two"
      <div id="three">
         <a href="foo.html">something</a>
```

...etc

I want to format div#one but only if the link inside of #one is a specific page like "foo.html".

I have tried several things but here is one example of what I have tried to use...

```
a[href *="foo"] #one:parent {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Is there a way to do this using css selectors, js or jQuery?  I've included a code snippet below for testing...

```css
a[href *="foo"] #one:parent {
        background-color: #FF0000;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="one">
       <div id="two"
          <div id="three">
             <a href="foo.html">something</a>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Everywhere I have searched for an answer has only given clues to how to do this with parent elements that are just one parent above but not several divs as in this example.

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's `.parents()` method: https://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: CSS does not have a way to walk backwards and does not have contains() like jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS you cannot but with JS you can simply consider `parentNode`:

```js
document.querySelector('a[href *="foo"]').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

```css
#one {
 padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
    <div id="three">
      <a href="foo.html">something</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you have n parent and you don't know the number you can create a loop to find your element:

```js
var a = document.querySelector('a[href *="foo"]');
while (a.parentNode.getAttribute('id') != "one") {
  a = a.parentNode;
}
a.parentNode.style.background = "red";
```

```css
#one {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
    <div id="three">
      <div>
        <a href="foo.html">something</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First options sort of works.  Second one doesn't seem to work. The first option will find the "foo" but then it alters not just that parent node but all of them with the same id "one".

Comment: @user2284703 both option are *idea* and not generic code :) you need of coure for adjust them for your real situation. The trick is that with JS you have the parentNode that allow you to get the parent of an element ;)

Comment: No worries.  It works... I just had a typo that I kept overlooking ("s.parentNode" instead of "a.parentNode" on the second line).  Thanks.